# How do I convert a node's bounding box to a different coordinate system?

Tags: scenekit

Nodes in SceneKit have a bounding box, which consists of two points: one with the smallest of all coordinates of the node, and the other with the largest of all coordinates of the node. These coordinates are in the node's own coordinate system, and I do not see how to find the bounding box in a different coordinate system.

For example, say we have a node with a unit box geometry like this, with the axes marked by `.` or `:`:

```
       :
  A---------+
  |    :    |
..|....:....|...
  |    :    |
  +---------B
       :
```

In the node's own coordinate system, A is (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5) and B is (0.5, 0.5, 0.5). If the box is position at (45, 0, 0) in the world's coordinate system, A would be (44.5, -0.5, -0.5) and B would be (45.5, 0.5, 0.5). We can get those values by calling `-[SCNNode getBoundingBoxMin:max:]` and then calling `-[SCNNode convertPosition:toNode:]`.

But what if the node is rotated 45° around the Z axis, so that in the world coordinate system, it looks like this?

```
        A
      /   \
    /       \
...+.........+...
    \       /
      \   /
        B
```

If you call `-[SCNNode convertPosition:toNode:]` in this situation, you'll get a messed up bounding box that has no width!

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to transform a (axis aligned) bounding box from one node to another, you need to transform the 8 vertex of the bbox (not just the min and max):

(min.x, min.y, min.z)
(max.x, min.y, min.z)
(min.x, max.y, min.z)
(max.x, max.y, min.z)
(min.x, min.y, max.z)
(max.x, min.y, max.z)
(min.x, max.y, max.z)
(max.x, max.y, max.z)

then parse these 8 transformed vertex and find the new transformed min and max.